# Como autenticar um usuário em app android que utiliza o login do Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, oauth2

Estou criando um aplicativo Android onde o usuário terá que se cadastrar para ter acesso ao conteúdo do aplicativo (um login). Para isso, uso por padrão o famoso Login do Facebook.
Quando o usuário logar através do botão do Facebook, eu aciono meu serviço REST que vai cadastrá-lo na base de dados remota. É ai que surgem as minhas dúvidas:

- Na minha base de dados remota, atualmente eu tenho os campos `username`, `email` e `password`. Já que estou usando o Login do Facebook (OAuth), qual seria a maneira correta/esperada/padrão de se fazer isso?
- Mesmo usando o login do facebook, é uma boa prática após o sucesso do login Facebook eu chamar uma activity para o usuário preencher `username` e `senha`? Faz sentido? Ou como o login do facebook ja fez a parte trabalhosa de autenticar o usuário, eu só preciso ter o campo `email` em minha base de dados?

Estou meio perdido em relação a isso e gostaria de receber orientações de vocês.

Comment: Há 4 votos para fechar a sua pergunta como "principalmente baseada em opiniões". Eu discoro, pois no meu entender as suas perguntas são dúvidas pontuais sobre o comportamento da API do facebook e como proceder com ela. No entanto, concordo que a redação original da pergunta poderia ser melhorada, pois do jeito que estava, até convidava algum leitor a responder de forma opinativa, embora não seja o propósito. Editei a pergunta para resolver isso e evitar o fechamento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou montando um banco de dados parecido com o que você quer, a única diferença é que no meu aplicativo, o usuário poderá logar tanto pelo Facebook, como pelo Google ou pelo próprio sistema de autenticação do meu aplicativo, e se as contas (Facebook, Google, meu App) pertencer ao mesmo dono (detectado via e-mail), então eles possuirão um mesmo único usuário no aplicativo. Estou modelando o banco de dados para dar suporte, independentemente de quantos meios de autenticação eu for utilizar.

No meu caso, um mesmo usuário pode ter 2 contas, ex: Facebook, Google. Ou até mesmo 3 contas, ex: Facebook, Google, Meu App.

Explicando como funciona: Cada usuário "user" pode ter um ou mais "identity", cade "identity" é um meio de conexão utilizado pelo usuário. Na tabela "identity", há a coluna "user_id" que aponta para o usuário, a coluna "adapter" indica qual o meio utilizado (facebook,google,meu_app), e em "hash", é armazenado o ID do usuário que é retornado pelo Facebook ou pelo Google quando utiliza as APIs deles. No caso de ser um acesso pelo sistema próprio de login do seu aplicativo (meu_app), então o hash armazenará a senha que ele cadastrou, criptografado com bCrypt, no meu caso.

Na hora do login, você deve adquirir o e-mail de acesso, seja pelo seu aplicativo (inserido pelo seu sistema de login), ou seja pelo Facebook ou Google, a própria API deles retorna o e-mail também. Assim, na lógica do login de seu serviço REST, você deve verificar se esse e-mail já é existente na tabela "user", pois se for, significa que o usuário já existe, certo? Nesse caso você vai pegar o ID desse usuário vai verificar se já existe também um "identity" para o meio de conexão utilizado. Para isso verifique se o "adapter" coincide, se coincidir bem, verifique se o "hash" também coincide, se coincidir, legal! Significa que o usuário já possui uma conta, e já logou utilizando aquele meio. Se não tiver esse "identity", então você deverá cadastrar. O mesmo vale se o usuário não existir, então você terá que cadastrar tanto o usuário, quanto o próprio "identity".

**Editando:** Falei e falei e acho que não respondi suas dúvidas principais. Então aqui vai:

Para a primeira pergunta, acho que o que eu escrevi acima responde. Coloquei uma imagem também.

Para a segunda dúvida, não vejo necessidade de fazer o usuário preencher username e senha, na verdade não faz sentido, considerando que se o usuário optou fazer login pelo Facebook, é porque ele não quer ficar criando usuário e senha. Além disso, todo esse processo de login é feito em um ambiente seguro do Facebook, a API cuida de tudo isso, você só precisará de cuidar da parte de armazenar o usuário no BD, caso a conexão for de sucesso. O que talvez seja interessante fazer, é uma etapa para finalizar o cadastro, caso deseje saber alguma informação adicional que não é retornado pelo Facebook.

Qualquer dúvida ou sugestão, estarei acompanhando!

Comment: Valeu YoSH. Ótima explicação e ótima logica. Seu material sana grande parte das minhas dúvidas. Obrigado!

Comment: Qualquer dúvida quanto a implementação no Android, fiz a implementação do Google e do Facebook ontem mesmo em um aplicativo da minha startup, portanto a ideia está fresquinha na minha mente, hehe. Mas estou feliz que a resposta tenha sanado grande parte das suas dúvidas, tinham me negativado nesta resposta, ainda não sei porque, toda minha implementação foi feita com base em várias pesquisas, várias "Melhor Resposta" do Stackoverflow internacional, e está funcionando legal no meu aplicativo.

Comment: Já que você me deu essa abertura, uma duvida que tenho é sobre a autorização do REST. Neste caso, como autentica-la no Cliente que consome o recurso (a app Android). Você usa a BASIC ou Digest? Quando a negativação da sua resposta, creio que alguém não intendeu a sua ideia - se é que não tem como intende-la, já que está muito clara e bem explicada.

Comment: Na verdade o termo correto seria autorização, certo? para que somente usuarios cadastrados na minha app possam consumir o meu webservice

Comment: Exatamente, "autorização" é o termo correto para o que você quer se referir. Eu não estou utilizando nem Basic nem Digest. Estou utilizando a autorização baseada em Tokens. Conheço desenvolvedores que se deram muito bem (a startup rendeu milhões), a aplicação deles utilizava esse método de autorização, e funcionava (funciona) muito bem. Acredito que na relação simplicidade/segurança, ela se destaca.

Comment: A Basic e a Digest são fáceis de implementar, porém a segurança delas é menor, elas são formas mais antigas de autenticação. O Digest que é mais seguro que o Basic, aplica um MD5 encrypt hash, porém essa forma de criptografia já é possível quebra-la por força-bruta (método de quebra de senhas), ainda mais se for uma senha fácil. Fora eles, tem a que estou usando, o "Token-based authorization". O OAuth também que é ótimo, mas a implementação é bem complexa. E o HMAC, utilizada pela Amazon, uma das mais recentes formas de autenticação, é complexa, talvez não mais que o OAuth, mas é bem segura.

Comment: Hmm, intendi. Você saberia me indicar um tutorial legal de autorização baseada em Token?

Comment: Olha, eu me baseio sempre em tutoriais em Inglês, stackoverflow é uma maravilha, mas a maioria das vezes só encontro o que quero no Inglês, se estiver tudo bem, aqui vai o link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147654/how-should-i-implement-token-based-authentication-to-a-set-of-web-apis-in-a-se

Comment: Otimo! Mais uma vez obrigado YoSH

Answer (score 0):

### O BÁSICO PARA UMA IMPLEMENTAÇÃO:

- Facebook App - Configure, crie um simples link de login.
- [Facebook SDK - Configure o SDK para poder utilizar a api.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)
- Facebook App ID - Utilize o ID de seu app:

1 - Abra **res/values/strings.xml**

2 - Adicione uma nova string com o nome *facebook_app_id* e ponha se id nela.

3 - Abra **AndroidManifest.xml** e adicione isso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

4 -  Adicione um meta-data element para a aplicação:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    ...
</application>
```

5 - Para usar o Facebook Login ou Share, basta adicionar o FacebookActivity no seu manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
          android:configChanges=
                 "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

### RESPONDENDO SUAS PERGUNTAS:

Para interagir com banco de dados MySQL, precisamos construir uma API em primeiro lugar. O trabalho da API é fazer com que o pedido do cliente, interaja com banco de dados e, finalmente, dar a resposta de volta ao cliente.

⇒ métodos GET / POST ⇒ Interagindo com banco de dados, inserindo / busca de dados. ⇒ Finalmente dará resposta de volta em formato JSON

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

[Fonte](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3)